# Category of metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Is there a standard/good reference text that does [category of metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_metric_spaces)?

Say, it seems that by looking at this category one can recover everything about particular metric space up to scaling --- is it written somewhere, or does it follow from something standard?

Comment: I had never seen "*metric maps*" but they're well often called "*1-Lipschitz maps*".

Comment: The obvious choice of morphisms between metric space is continuous functions, but then you have the category of **metrisable topological spaces**.  Elsewhere, morphisms are supposed to preserve structure, which is what 1-Lipschitz maps do.

Comment: Bill Lawvere has a way to look at this as a particular case of enriched categories. See http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/1/tr1abs.html and the nLab entry on the subject.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski I don't think the Lawvere paper, seminal though it might be (waves to the Edinburgh magnitude crew) serves well as a reference for the category that the OP is asking for. I assume (but Anton Petrunin can correct me if I am wrong) that what is desired is a reference which will state the properties of this category (existence and nature of finite limits/colimits) and its relation with other categories via various adjoint functors

Comment: Anton: perhaps you could add some detail or examples of what you're looking for? as in, what kinds of definitions/theorems/facts are you hoping for such a text to contain?

Comment: In fact there are several classes of maps that define categories with metric spaces as objects: *Bounded, Uniformly Continuous, Hölder, Lipschitz, 1-Lipschitz, Isometries,...* and their local versions, e.g. *Locally Lipschitz.* Plus, those classes that are already defined between topological spaces (*Continuous, Proper,...*)

Comment: I would not call it a standard reference but we needed this category in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05524.pdf.

Comment: @YemonChoi, I need some basics, a treatment of injective metric spaces for example.

Comment: @YemonChoi Regarding Lawveres paper: I always wanted to know more about the relationship between the $L^p$ business from functional analysis and the remark by Lawevere on $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$.

Comment: @GerritBegher Yes, but what does that have to do with Anton Petrunin's question?

Comment: Can I just point out to those who are, almost by reflex, reaching for the Lawvere paper, that Anton is concerned with the category whose objects are metric spaces, not metric spaces as categories, nor with the right "categorification" of the notion of metric spaces. I am not familiar with Isbell's papers but surely they would be more relevant to this particular question?

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that AFAICT Lawvere deals with V-enriched categories for V a suitable category, obtaining a notion of "metric space" which does not satisfy the symmetry axiom. It may be the case that Lawvere's category is from a certain POV the correct one to study, but it does mean that properties of the category Anton is asking about will have to be translated from properties of the category of "Lawvere metric spaces" by various symmetrization arguments

Comment: @YCor, ' I had never seen "metric maps" ' ==== I was using the term "metric maps" (and metric category) in my papers over half a century ago.

Comment: The question needs more focus.

Comment: Is it fair to reformulate the question as: Does every automorphism of this category take each object to an isometrically equivalent object?

Comment: @MattF. "up to rescaling". For $\lambda>0$ one has the obvious automorphism $(X,d)\mapsto (X,\lambda d)$ on objects, $f\mapsto f$ on maps.

Comment: @MattF. No --- I need a reference (it is easy to prove, and likely it is done somewhere).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, It seems that there is no such reference --- so the question has no answer, but I do not see a way to make it more focused.